# How to migrate theme from magento1.9 to magento2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, theme, magento-2.0.7, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated data from magento1.9 to magento2 but want to transfer magento1.9 theme to magento2

Answer (score 2):

You can not migrate themes from Magento 1.x to magento 2. The only thing that you can migrate is Data (Products, Customers and orders) and also configuration values.

Extensions and themes can not be migrated. You need to search for compatible Magento 2 Theme and Extension Or Develop it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing that `magento 1.x` and `magento 2.0` has different file structure you can migrate data but how can you migrate code b'coz `magento1.x` and `magento2` has different code and pattern , and theme also contain some part of code and css and all bases of structure of your phtml file.

So that's why you can not migrate code/theme from `magento1.9` to `magento2.0`